# Search field number solr not working in java

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to perform query on solr as follows and I am not getting.

My query:

```
String[] PROJECOES = { "*, score" };

    try {

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("number:\"" + "03001534320168050079" + "\" ");
        query.setStart(1);
        query.setRows(1);

        query.setFields(PROJECOES);

        QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();

        System.out.println(query.getQuery());
        System.out.println(results.size());



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My field in solr schema:

```
<field name="number" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

My config fieldType:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

PS: The query that only working for texts in java. This same query works in solr application manager.
I'm using version solr 4.10.

Comment: If you're going to query exact matches for "number-ish" values, try to use a StrField for that - not a text_general field.

Comment: @MatsLindh not working!